# reinstate Jquery features after flash callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3

I have a page that uses the jQuery.swfobject plugin to embed 5 flash items into a page and each flash item has a callback using externalInterface. The callbacks work when I have the js function outside of $(document).ready(function() but the jQuery animations do not fire - the ajax load however does.

Does anyone know how to get the animations working too, code below:

```
function pageLoader(galID) {
$('#menu').hide();
$('#holder_gallery').load("feeds.php", {gallery: galID}, function(){
$('#holder_gallery ul li a').slimbox();
$('#holder_gallery').jScrollPane();
$('.galleryTitle').text(galleryTitle);
$('.galleryTitle').fadeIn(2000);
$('#holder_gallery').fadeIn(2000);

$('.ghost').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 300);
        });
    });});}
```

The main parts above work well - I just want to add the gloss back in using the fadeIn functions and the animate on hovers. The jScrollpane reinstates itself as does the .load

Regards,

MM

Comment: It would be nice if you could show a simple demo where the issue can be observed.

Comment: http://7souls.co.uk/test.php

Should show the page as is

Comment: I get JS error 'galleryTitle is not defined' when I click on a gallery name. Seems like the problem has nothing to do with Flash or jQuery.

Comment: BTW, each is not necessary. Just write $('.ghost').hover(...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about binding the `.ghost` elements in the callback of the `#holder_gallery` animation

```
//existing code
$('#holder_gallery').fadeIn(2000, function(){
  $('.ghost', this).each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);
     },
      function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 300);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: czarchaic & thorn, a combination of your comments has resolved the rebinding of the event.

1st I moved the $('.ghost') above the slimbox and jScrollpane calls and then removed the galleryTitle parts as these are yet to be implemented and may not be required by the client after all - doing these two things has resulted in a page that now loads and performs correctly.

Many thanks for your input - it is greatly appreciated :D

MM